# Was there hope for these characters in The Lost Boys?

Tags: the-lost-boys

This question has been tearing my family apart so I'd like some help.

In *The Lost Boys*, Michael is turned into a vampire by David and his crew.  It is revealed that, like Star and that little kid, Michael is not a full vampire yet as he has not committed his first kill.  His brother Sam reads a comic book saying that if the head vampire is killed, the other vampires will be turned back.  After killing off David and the others, the true head vampire is killed and the half-vamps are turned back.  My question is this: **would David and his crew have been safely turned back at this point?**

My dad claimed that since Michael and Star were not full vampires, killing the head would have only worked for them and not David, but I said that the comic book said that *all* vampires would be turned back.  Is this specifically answered in the movie, or can we only infer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the comic is accurate, David and the other *full vampires* would have remained vampires. The death of the "Head Vampire" in a nest only allows **those that have not yet transformed** to return to fully human form.

> “My brother,” Sam insisted, “is not a bloodsucker yet.” He pointed to
> the vampire comic he’d brought along for this very reason. “Look. **It
> says here that if you kill the head vampire, then all the half
> vampires will return to normal.”** He looked up at the Frogs in triumph.
> “If my brother’s a vampire, believe me, as weird as he’s acting, he’s
> only half. I mean, Michael always acted sort of weird to begin with.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Lost Boys: Official Movie Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/329096.The_Lost_Boys)</sup></sub>

The same scene from the movie has pretty much the same info

> **Sam:** *It says here that if you kill the head vampire **all half-vampires** will return to normal.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Lost Boys: Movies transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=lost-boys-the)</sup></sub>